# redis terminate called after throwing an instance of 'sw::redis::MovedError'

Tags: redis

I try to build a redis cluster follow this [cluster-tutorial](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial)

I try to use this tutorial(RedLock) to write code[Red Lock](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus#redlock)

Got the following error ：
**terminate called after throwing an instance of 'sw::redis::MovedError'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redlock does not work with Redis Cluster. Instead, it works with Single Redis instances. You should run your code with N dependent Redis instances, NOT a Redis Cluster.

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'sw::redis::MovedError'

Seems that you're using [redis-plus-plus](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus/). You got this error, because you're trying to send commands to Redis Cluster with a `Redis` object.